# How to return different promises from a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

I have a `createOrder` function, that is supposed to return a promise. I have database calls in the function, and I'd like to resolve the promise of the `createOrder` function, when all database actions have finished.

The problem is that the typescript compiler don't let me return the promise from inside the database function returned promise because it thinks that the function declaration (return a Promise) isn't fulfilled:

```
createOrder(order:Array<Cartitem>, sum:number):Promise<Array<Cartitem>> {
    this.db.put(newOrder)
        .then((r)=>{
           //other operations
           return new Promise<Array<Cartitem>>((resolve) => {
               resolve(order);
           });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
           console.log('put order:', err);
           // return new Promise<Array<Cartitem>>((reject) => {
           //   reject(order);
           // });
        });
}
```

I can return a Promise at the end of the function, but that is not good for anything of course except for the compiler. Should I use a simple callback here?

Comment: Thanks for all of you, this was fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the Promise as your function's return value, and resolve it in your inner promise callbacks:

```
createOrder(order:Array<Cartitem>, sum:number):Promise<Array<Cartitem>>  
{
   return new Promise<Array<Cartitem>>((resolve) => {
      this.db.put(newOrder)
        .then((r)=>{
            //other operations
           resolve(order);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           console.log('put order:', err);
           reject(err);
        });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're doing in "other operations," you either use the promise created by calling `then` on `this.db.put`'s promise if you can:

```
createOrder(order:Array<Cartitem>, sum:number):Promise<Array<Cartitem>> {
    return this.db.put(newOrder)
        .then((r)=>{
           //other operations
           return order;                   // Resolves the one created by `then`
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
           console.log('put order:', err);
           throw err;                      // Rejects the one created by `then`
        });
    });
}
```

...or if you can't for some reason, create your promise earlier, and make your call to `this.db.put` inside its initialization callback:

```
createOrder(order:Array<Cartitem>, sum:number):Promise<Array<Cartitem>> {
    return new Promise<Array<Cartitem>>((resolve) => {
        this.db.put(newOrder)
            .then((r)=>{
               //other operations
               resolve(order);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
               console.log('put order:', err);
               reject(err); // You had `order` here, but presumably it would be `err`
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
createOrder(order:Array<Cartitem>, sum:number):Promise<Array<Cartitem>> {
    return this.db.put(newOrder)
        .then((r)=>{
           //other operations
           return new Promise<Array<Cartitem>>((resolve) => {
               resolve(order);
           });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
           console.log('put order:', err);
           // return new Promise<Array<Cartitem>>((reject) => {
           //   reject(order);
           // });
           return null
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should actually add the `return` of `this.db.put` (and the whole expression following it).

As it stands, you are invoking `this.db.put`, and chaining a callback in the then branch, but you aren't returning anything to the caller. Subsequently, callers might expect to be able to `.then` off of the result of `createOrder`, but in plain-old JavaScript, it will fail, since the result will be undefined.

You can also just `resolve(order)` in `.then`, rather than return a Promise of array etc.